# How to implement three first layers of network from Simple Audio Recognition Tensorflow tutorial in java

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, neural-network, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use model trained using Simple Audio Recognition Tensorlow tutorial in Android application, but I want to implement three first layers not in network, but on CPU side. Basicly I used (without changing anything) training from Tensorflow tutorial, but freezed model without decoding sample data, calculating spectrogram and mfcc:

wav_data_placeholder

```
Tensor("wav_data:0, shape=(), dtype=string)
```

decoded_sample_data

```
DecodeWav(audio=(tf.Tensor 'decoded_sample_data:0' shape=(16000, 1) dtype=flat32), sample_rate(tf.Tensor 'decoded_sample_data:1' shape=() dtype=int32))
```

spectrogram

```
Tensor("AudioSpectrogram:0, shape=(1, 98, 257), dtype=float32)
```

fingerprint_input

```
Tensor("Mfcc:0, shape=(1, 98, 40), dtype=float32)
```

---

So my freezed model has input shape (1, 98, 40) and takes values that are calculated by the mfcc method which has input values from spectrogram output which has input from decoded sample data.

I tried librosa mfcc implementation in java, but unfortunately, it does not provide the same results.

How can I compute my .wav file in Android application to successfully satisfy my model input to get the right predictions?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking on stackoverflow! It might be worth having a look at the "how to ask" page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - basically, though, can you tell us what coding you've tried so far? Putting your attempts into the question will help us to help you